# Rendering for large MatLab figure is slow

Tags: performance, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm using MatLab R2014B on Win 8.1 I have a figure with two sub-plots. The data for the first sub-plot is about 700,000 points; the second is about 50,000 points. When I display it or manipulate it in any way (zoom, say), there's a huge lag in time, up to about 30 seconds. Obviously I'd like to improve performance. Here's what I know:

- If I break it into 4 plots, each covering 1/4 of the data, performance is fast. Much more than 4 times as fast. The difference seems exponential.
- A colleague (running R2014A I believe) has a machine that should be slower but in fact the figure displays with near-realtime speed.

The problem is perhaps how the figure is being rendered. I ran MatLab's "opengl info" and it reports that the Software flag is false. That should mean it's using the display's hardware rendering.

So maybe the display adapter isn't set quite right. My machine (it's a Lenovo laptop) has two display adapters: Intel HD Graphics 3000 and NVIDIA NVS 4200M. I don't know why there are both or whether there are any relevant settings.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're running it through your integrated graphics processor (Intel HD Graphics 3000) rather than your dedicated graphics processor (NVIDIA NVS 4200M). If your Lenovo has "switchable graphics" enabled, you should be able to switch to the NVIDIA, or check that you are indeed rendering through that. Right click on your power manager in the taskbar. If you see a menu item that says "switchable graphics," you can change it to your NVIDIA. Note, you'll have to close out of MATLAB to do switch.

It does sound like a slowdown caused by the rendering configuration. When you run `opengl info` in MATLAB, what device is listed as "Renderer"?

Comment: Version: '4.3.0'
                           Vendor: 'NVIDIA Corporation'
                         Renderer: 'NVS 4200M/PCIe/SSE2'
                   MaxTextureSize: 16384
                           Visual: 'Visual 0x07, (RGBA 32 bits (8 8 8 8), Z depth 24 bits, Hardware acceleration, Double buffer, Antialias 8 samples)'
                         Software: 'false'
        SupportsGraphicsSmoothing: 1
    SupportsDepthPeelTransparency: 1
       SupportsAlignVertexCenters: 1
                       Extensions: {272x1 cell}
               MaxFrameBufferSize: 16384

Comment: It sounds like you're using the right graphics card. 700,000 data points is a lot. What makes you say your colleague's machine should be slower?

Comment: It's an older motherboard with a lot less memory. But apparently the video adapter works better. Or R2014A is more efficient. I might try reverting to that if I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to manipulate it (say you only want an image file), you can always create your figure with `figure('Visible','Off')` and save it without actually showing the figure on screen.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB releases ever since R2014b use a new graphics engine which is known to be extremely slow with large data sets; see for example
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/337755

The solution has nothing to do with graphics drivers etc. Revert back to MATLAB R2014a and stay there.

Comment: Reverting to R2014a is temporary workaround, not a solution. Progress marches on, with or without you, and it's not a good idea to have your code base stuck on a deprecated platform.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function, [plotECG](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59296), that enables you to show plots with millions of samples. It includes sliders for quick scrolling and zooming.

If you have multiple timeseries and want them to be displayed in a synchronized way, you can pass them as matrix all at once and define the key 'AutoStackSignals', followed by a cell array of strings with the signal's names. Then, the signals are shown one below the other in the same axis with the corresponding name as YTickLabel.

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59296